# transition from @RunWith to @ExtendWith

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I need the `methodInvoker` of `JUnit4` in `JUnit5` to wrap the execution of the test itself in a `lambda` expression. The given Interfaces like AfterTestExecutionCallback will not allow manipulating the execution itself. Kindly guide me with `JUnit` 4 to 5 migration? The transition from `@RunWith` to `@ExtendWith`. How can you wrap the execution of the test itself with JUnit 5?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do so via implementing and registering an `InvocationInterceptor`

```java
public class SwingEdtInterceptor implements InvocationInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void interceptTestMethod(Invocation<Void> invocation,
            ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method> invocationContext,
            ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Throwable {

        AtomicReference<Throwable> throwable = new AtomicReference<>();

        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            try {
                invocation.proceed();
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                throwable.set(t);
            }
        });
        Throwable t = throwable.get();
        if (t != null) {
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

Copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-intercepting-invocations

Seems like your use-case might be a candidate for Dynamic Tests, aka *Testlests*: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests -- did you give them a try?

Comment: This Interceptor was added in JUnit 5.5+